# Implicit Super Constructor Animal() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another Constructor

Tags: constructor

M not getting this error. Please explain why this error came and how to solve it. Thanks.

```
class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(String name) {
    }
}

public class Animal {
    public Animal(String name) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
public Dog(String name) {
    super(name)
}
```

will solve your problem?